# Linked Data with google custom search API

Tags: api, semantic-web, linked-data

I just want to make a project that i got my data from google custom search 
and then make these data as a linked data so i searched for this 
and got that there's something called  implement wrapper around your api and found something called "API2LOD" that takes data from API and make them linked and publish them as rdf description. 
Can i use this for my project or there any other generic wrapper like "API2LOD" to use? 
i'll appreciate your help, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to start by using Java library from Google: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/customsearch/v1.

Once you have the results fetched in memory, I suggest to [model your search results domain using Eclipse Lyo](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Lyo/ToolchainModellingAndCodeGenerationWorkshop#Domain_Specification_View) and generate Java classes using its generator.

Finally, use [Jena Model Helper](http://download.eclipse.org/lyo/docs/1.0/apidocs/org/eclipse/lyo/oslc4j/provider/jena/JenaModelHelper.html) to marshal the POJOs into a Jena model that can be stored in a triplestore (Jena or any SPARQL-compatible store).